# Delete image row and delete image from directory

Tags: php, mysql, unlink

As the title states I'm trying to delete the image row information from the database and delete the actual image from the gallery directory.

If I run this it deletes the row from my database:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$deletepic = DB::getInstance()->delete('gallery', array(
    'id', '=', $id
));
```

If I do the following it will delete the image from the directory, but will not delete the row.

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$gallery = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `file_name` FROM `gallery` WHERE ID = $id");

foreach($gallery->results() as $file_name){

$pic =  ($file_name->file_name);
}

$deletepics = DB::getInstance()->delete('gallery', array(
    'id', '=', $id,
    unlink('../../images/gallery/'.$pic)
));
```

I can't understand how to get the name of the image without running the select query, but I need to run it like that so I can unlink the image.

Can someone help me combined the delete row and unlink function here?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
$deletepics = DB::getInstance()->delete('gallery', array('id', '=', $id));
unlink('../../images/gallery/'.$pic);
```

Comment: Perfect that worked, didn't realize I couldn't have the unlink function inside the array. Thanks for the help! I'll accept this as soon as the system lets me.